# Regex for parsing a string and get output based on operator separation

Tags: python, regex

I need to use regex in python and get the necessary values from the input I am providing here.

**Example 1:**

```
jack_001D_ast/jule_111D_ast
```

I need a regex for the above input to get the same in list as follows:

```
[jack_001D_ast, jule_111D_ast]
```

I achieved this using the below format:

```
 input = jack_001D_ast/jule_111D_ast

 re.findall("\w+,*", input)
```

**Example 2:**

But in the below case it is returning as follows:

```
(jack_001D_ast+jule_111D_ast)/5
```

resulted output:

```
[jack_001D_ast, jule_111D_ast, 5]
```

Expected:

```
[jack_001D_ast, jule_111D_ast]
```

Here I dont want the 5 to be taken here in output. Need regex for the same

**Example 3:**

```
(jack_001D_ast+jule_111D_ast)%5
```

Also it should be working for below example.

So on the whole output should be a list of variables which is separated by operators.

some one help me with the same.

Comment: If you want to match valid Python identifiers, use `r'[^\W\d]\w*'`

Comment: What about string literals? What type of strings do you pass to the regex?

Answer (score 1):

Is `_ast` there in every case? Then you could do it with `\w+_ast`